# Телеграм бот на aiogram через webhook не отвечает на сообщения

Tags: python, aiogram, nginx, webhook

Есть выделенный домен, ssl сертификат, сервер на ubuntu и скрипт на python. Через polling всё работает, бот реагирует на сообщения. Через webhook скрипт запускается, но на сообщения не отвечает. Что можно сделать? Используется nginx

Код файла bot.py:

```
import openpyxl
import os
import asyncio
import logging


from aiogram import Bot, types, executor
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.webhook import SendMessage
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.utils.executor import start_webhook


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
storage = MemoryStorage()
TOKEN = 'token'
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

WEBHOOK_HOST = 'https://domainname.ru'
WEBHOOK_PATH = '/'
WEBHOOK_URL = f"{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}"
WEBAPP_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
WEBAPP_PORT = 8443

async def on_startup(dp):
    logging.warning('starting')
    await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL)

async def on_shutdown(dp):
    logging.warning('Shutting down..')
    await bot.delete_webhook()
    await dp.storage.close()
    await dp.storage.wait_closed()
    logging.warning('Bye!')

#...handlers, script body

executor.start_webhook(
    dispatcher=dp,
    webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
    on_startup=on_startup,
    on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
    skip_updates=True,
    host=WEBAPP_HOST,
    port=WEBAPP_PORT,
)
```

Comment: 1) проверь вывод https://api.telegram.org/botТОКЕН/getWebhookInfo 2) посмотри логи запросов на твой сервер в nginx (/var/log/nginx/)

Comment: @askarr 
`{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://botdomainname.ru/","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":0,"max_connections":40,"ip_address":"myip"}}`

вот такой вывод

Comment: @askarr спустя время поменялся статус по getwebhookinfo
```{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://botdomainname.ru/","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":3,"last_error_date":1707307085,"last_error_message":"Connection timed out","max_connections":40,"ip_address":"myip"}}```

Comment: @askarr connection timed out появляется сразу же как я отправляю /start боту

Comment: в папке (/var/log/nginx/) два файла access.log и error.log и оба пустые